# How to display facebook shared contents in my web page?

Tags: php, facebook-apps

I am creating a web page for a facebook app, I was wondering how to display all the shared contents such as photos, links, videos, etc. of my friends in facebook in my web page? I am using PHP as a programming language.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone who have an idea about my question? thanks!

Comment: The shared content you are referring herein is the posts that you have made on any of your friends wall. Is it correct?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena No, i am referring to any contents shared by my friends. I would like to fetch those shared contents in a PHP page..

Comment: Sorry, for late reply but did you try using [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) for resolution of your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using FQL for retrieving the links from [link table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/links/) like this:-

> select title,summary,url,owner from link where owner IN (select target_id from connection where source_id = me() and target_type = 'user')

Status using [status table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/) like this:-

> select message from status where uid IN (select target_id from connection where source_id = me() and target_type = 'user')

Videos using [video table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/) like :-

> select title,description from video where owner IN (select target_id from connection where source_id = me() and target_type = 'user')

And similarly you can retrieve other details, though the number of results might vary and you might have to deal with paging as mentioned in this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/)